# SSMS Money Data Type Issue

Tags: types, ssms, precision, sqldatatypes, currency

When using the "Money" data type in  Microsoft SQL Server Management Server, How do I get the Information in the table to be displayed on a website with only 2 places after the decimal being displayed? I want to see "$14.99" instead of "$14.9900" any suggestions? My data type is Money and I am having no issues displaying the information, its just not coming out how I want it.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the formatting that would be best handled in the code powering the web page. What are you using to display your data? ASP.Net or something else?